# javascript remove embeded script tags

Tags: javascript

I am using wicket an mvc framework, which embeds the following script tags in the html which causes the page to reload every 60 secs.

I can't figure out how to disable this using wicket. Trying to see if I can do it using javascript. I want to write some javascript in my html that will remove this tag and its content

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
/*<![CDATA[*/
Wicket.Event.add(window, "load", function(event) { 
Wicket.TimerHandles['contentPanel17'] = setTimeout('Wicket.Ajax.ajax({\"c  \":\"contentPanel17\",\"u\":\"./?1-1.IBehaviorListener.0-viewPanel-contentPanel-view_panel-contentPanel\",\"i\":\"loading_indicator18\"});', 900000);
Wicket.TimerHandles['id121'] = setTimeout('Wicket.Ajax.ajax({\"u\":\"./?1-1.IBehaviorListener.0-\"});', 60000);
;});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: It seems you have the handler of the timeout. Try clearing it and see what happens.

Comment: I cannot clean it out because it is something the MVC does internally. Yes, If I know the MVC very well, i will be able to find a way to disable it. But I dont know the tech behind it, so trying to figure out another way